# Dynamic Schema on Azure Mobile Services with .net backend in production

Tags: xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure Mobile Services app with a .Net backend which is connected to by a Xamarin client.

The .net backend will have a website that is the admin interface.

The admin interface will be able to add tables to the database that I'd like the Xamarin client to be able to interact with without having to add a new TableController and update the client.

Any ideas on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to do this from the same site, please consider using [Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/) instead of Azure Mobile Services. The Mobile Services .NET runtime does not support MVC controllers, which is what you would probably use for the admin interface. Your MVC controllers could then leverage the same EntityFramework DbContext that the TableControllers are using.

Comment: Thanks for that, does that support dynamic data